# Unable to aggregate line segments while summing values

Tags: qgis, merge, dissolve, aggregate, v.clean

I've a layer with multilines, overlapping to a various degrees. I need to merge/dissolve them "downwards" while summing their values for the overlapping segments.

I made it to "Union" phase, the resulting layer is here [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lj0YgvEbCX84J4S_85o0WLG03xUy-804/view?usp=sharing), values to sum are in ROUND column. Following it, I tried v.clean and Aggregate (basically as suggested here [Summing attribute values of overlapping polyline portions in QGIS 3.0.3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294976/summing-attribute-values-of-overlapping-polyline-portions-in-qgis-3-0-3) ), but I'm kinda confused in options, and have come to thinking, that these tools actually cannot do this.

The task seems quite simple, yet I`m quite new to GIS and might be wrong. Found this thread [Overlapping line aggregation+trim in PostGIS, while summing values](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171880/overlapping-line-aggregationtrim-in-postgis-while-summing-values) which talks about just the same situation but is really a code in length of an A4 really the only solution?

Here's a sample of what I'm trying to achieve. [image: sample] I`s an actual segment from data after Aggregation but tool gave wrong results with many lines still overlapping, still, the idea is right. As a result, I want to have a flattened layer of line segments without overlapping, where each segment, i.e. color in sample, has a value, that is a sum of values of overlapping segments before flattening.

Note - I`d prefer a solution over a calculated final result, as the source data are dynamic and keep changing.

Note 2 - gave a go to the code in length of an A4 suggested in the other thread. Changed variables everywhere in the code and tried to create a virtual layer with it. No luck, it returned syntax error, which I was unable to identify. No wonder as I'm a total dumb when it comes to SQL, well, code in general.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the lines and attribute table, and you desired result (for example a paint drawing)

Comment: Sure, sample added. Still, it's hard to demonstrate overlapping, but it's in the added .shp file. Attribute table contains I guess 5 columns one of which contains the values to sum. Too much hassle to screenshot it.