# QGIS sum attribute values of overlapping line segments

Tags: qgis, line, union, aggregate

This is sort of follow-up to [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/420537/unable-to-aggregate-line-segments-while-summing-values). Not sure how I got it working a year ago, but now I'm across the same issue again. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1de2T05B2Vp4Ug908Ai7iKq8fInFBTTa-/view?usp=sharing) is a clean dataset which I believe is correct. It contains overlapping line segments with different attribute values. Those are actual river segments in Latvia with actual values based on bird observations.

What I struggle with is to Union all of the segments at each point wherever there's another segment's beginning or end. There can be tens of overlapping segments at some parts due to high record density. Apparently Union tool has some sort of limitation due to which it kinda cannot "cut" through multiple segments. Even after running the Union tool over this layer multiple times, I still get overlapping segments.

My ideal scenario is to achieve layer of segments, in which there's no single PARTIALLY overlapping part of a segment. So that there are either only single segments, or fully overlapped. Then to sum them down via Aggregate tool, as a final result getting a single-layered layer with summed values of overlapping segments.

Overlapping Analysis tool looks like doesn't work on Line geometries. Is there perhaps another tool that can cut through multiple line segments? Intersection deletes non-overlapping parts
which is not what I need.

I'll emphasize, that this is a question regarding how to do it, as well as regarding how to do it CORRECTLY. The values hopefully calculated after the Aggregate too will be then calculated against the length of the segments to calculate the mean value for the surveyed river segment. Thus, each split segment is important in the whole process and cannot be lost.

Comment: Looks like v.clean is the tool to use, yet, I`m also strugling with settings there. Which settings would be the best in given situation?